# Strange PHP tags

Tags: php

I got the code below from a tutorial that teaches how to make wordpress plugins. It has some unusual PHP tags. For example,

a) 3rd line from the bottom, there is an opening `<?php` tag.

b) And, also, after $base_map_url  is set, there is a closing `?>` tag.

This is very different from what I've learned, yet the code works.

c) Also, in all the plugins the author has built, there is an opening `<?php` tag at the very top but not a final closing one.

What is happening here, can you explain?

```
<?php
/*
 Plugin Name: Map plugin using shortcode
 Plugin URI: http://example
 Description: This plugin will get a map of whatever parameter is passed
 Author: Drew
 Version: 1.0
 Author URI: http://www.blah 
 */

function smp_map_it($addr)
{
    $addr = "1600 Pennsylvania Ave. Washington, D.C.";
    $base_map_url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=256x256&format=png&center=';
    ?>
    <h2>Your map:</h2>
    <img width="256" height="256"
        src="<?php echo $base_map_url . urlencode($addr); ?>" />
    <?php 
}

add_shortcode('map-it','smp_map_it');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just leaving a PHP block for HTML output.

Functions shouldn't really do that. That is why [WordPress gets so much crap](http://www.phpvs.net/2009/12/08/an-exercise-in-wordpress-integration-or-why-wordpress-sucks/), e.g. `the_content()` that just dumps content (as if people are too incompetent to use `echo`).

The best way to do it is simply have a *view* file which handles your HTML and some basic PHP constructs and control structures such as `echo`, `foreach`, `if`, etc.

The trailing `?>` in a file is unnecessary, and [Zend coding standards ask you to never place it](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html). It can often be the cause of *Headers already sent* when some pesky whitespace ends up after it.

Comment: o.k., thanks, is get_the_content() a special wordpress built in function?

Comment: @Micheal From memory it is, but you have to be *in the loop*, which is a nice way of saying *you need to store a bunch of state globally and then this whole mess works* :P

Comment: Doesn't `get_the_content()` return the content as a string? You're probably thinking of `the_content()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you close the PHP tag, it just becmes equal to:

```
echo ('<h2>Your map:</h2>
<img width="256" height="256"
    src="');
```

There are two approaces to coding PHP. One inserts PHP into HTML, this is used by frontend developers. Template languages use this style in general:

```
<img src="<?php echo ($url); ?>">
```

The other style is more like programming then template writing:

```
<?php
    echo (printf ('<img src="%s">', $url));
```

Comment: can you explain the logic about why there is an opening tag at the end, and a closing tag earlier in the code? what are the rules it is following?

Comment: why is it necessary to have the opening tag at the end?

Comment: @Michael All content in the file which is not enclosed in PHP tags are just sent to the user like plain HTML. You can step in-and-out PHP mode. You can even step out of PHP mode inside a for cycle. This techique results in hard-to-read code, so use only with a very good reason.

Comment: @Michael The last `<?php` is needed because a `function {` was stated earlier. You have to close the function with `}` unless the file would just give an error.

Comment: @vbence  It's very hard to read, so thanks for your explanation. so if the last <?php tag is needed to go with }, then why doesn't he use a closing php tag at the bottom ?>.  Is that closing php tag ?> optional?

Comment: @Michael Yes, closing PHP tag can be omitted. In fact I would suggest you not to use `?>` at the end of your PHP files because for example a newline character can easily slip afterwards and can produce unwanted output. Especially if your PHP file is an `include(...)` file.

Answer (score 2):

`<?php` marks the beginning of php code for the php parser

`?>` marks the end of php code for the php parser

`/*` marks the start of a comment which will be ignored by the parser

`*/` marks the end of a comment which will be ignored by the parser

Comment: Also of note, but not seen in the sample code is // for single line comments.

Answer (score 1):

It is not strange, it is crap. He is embeding HTML in PHP (sin anyway), and he is doing it bad.
Last PHP tag can remain open.

Comment: It's a sin, but is it a OOP sin? More a separation of concerns sin.

Comment: It's so sin, it might be win!

Comment: Well it breaks MVC, and is hardcoring width and height in HTML which also breaks strict HTML. <h2> doesn't belong there for sure.

Comment: If you're not going to help, just don't bother posting.

Comment: come on, how is it related to MVC?!?!? It is regular spaghetti.

Comment: @zerkms I saw WP somewhere or I need to go to sleep, anyway you are right it is spaghetti, but since it is a plugin I reckon it should have been MVC. @Chris You are right, if they stop writing plugins like this, then I have helped.

Comment: @webarto: yep, you're right. Cannot get accustomed into the fact that MVC can be implemented using procedural paradigm.

Comment: @webarto  why can the last PHP tag remain open?

Comment: @Michael Please read http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Answer (score 1):

This function is sending output directly rather than using echo statements where the content falls outside the php tags.

While this kind of approach is often discouraged (coming out of the PHP context while in a function body isn't considered good practice) there isn't anything about it that would make it not function.

It is however, very bad code.  Outputting in function bodies very often leads to header errors and other comforts when trying to perform redirects or session management.

Comment: can you explain the actual logic of the tags? why is the opening tag at the end? and a closing one earlier?

Comment: A lot of Wordpress code unfortunately ends up this way.  Many plugin functions can be seen outputing direct rather than returning values.  There are many plugins authored by people who predominately identify themselves as designers, and so they are less familiar in general with OOP and coding standards.  Additionally, the "main article loop" structure kind of reinforces this bad practice IMHO since many people just want to output article data in the loop.

Comment: The tags appear the way they do because the PHP code enclosing the function definitions and actions needs to still be in the PHP context.  It's just the headers and HTML that need to be put out to the browser directly when the function is called.

Comment: ah, I think I get it. when you want to output in a function, do you reverse the usual order of the php tags? for example,   ?>  outputted content <?php

Comment: Right - the content outside the PHP context is treated just like any non-server logic (ie HTML.)  It's not something to be encouraged.  The function should instead build up the required string data and use return to send it out to whatever called it.  Then the return value could be echoed in the view.